# Datanode is Not Starting in Hadoop after Kerberos Auth

Tags: hadoop

I have given permission to `/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data`.

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data : 
EPERM: Operation not permitted
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2505)
2017-03-14 20:10:51,169 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/" 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2505)
2017-03-14 20:10:51,172 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2017-03-14 20:10:51,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the owner of that directory on the local file system match the service of the Kerberos principal the datanode is now using? So if it is hdfs/, then the directory (and all under it) should be owned by hdfs.